# page header changing

Tags: html, css

My problem is that our website design header is transparent when you are at the top of the page.

But when you scroll down the header changes and becomes background white.

I want to my header be always like second time when you scroll down, I want white background for header.

You can also check http://modern-house.ge

Comment: this is more of a CSS work rather then wordpress.. Ask any HTML developer to help you out

Comment: Check WordPress admin panel. You can find theme options in the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your javascript a class 'menu-hidden' is being added when you scroll to a certain point and class 'menu-show' is being removed

A quick fix with CSS would be to find the class 'menu-hidden' in your theme and remove this. You can find this in '/wp-content/themes/sailing/assets/css/custom-style.css'.

```
transform: translate(0,-100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%);
-moz-transform: translate(0,-100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0,-100%);
-o-transform: translate(0,-100%);
```

Warning: If you update the theme this will get over ridden and the hide and display on scroll will start again. You should look into making a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and do your changes in there so they are never overwritten by a theme update.